# A way to SELECT fields from one table and INSERT to another?

Tags: mysql, insert-into

I have two tables, TableA and TableB

TableA has 9 fields
TableB has 7 fields

There are 2 fields (id and name) that are identical in both tables, is there a way to select ONLY these two fields from TableA and insert them into TableB?

I have looked at the INSERT INTO... SELECT method using this statement:

```
INSERT INTO TableB
SELECT id, name
FROM TableA
WHERE id = 1
```

But I get the following error:

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I assume this error is not allowing me to insert only 2 fields into the table? If so, is there a way around this or an alternative method?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO TableB(id, name)
SELECT id, name FROM TableA where id = 1;
```

One would have to assume that the column names in TableB match TableA otherwise you would need to put in the right names.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the column names for TableB (and possibly specify TableA.id in the WHERE clause):

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, name)
SELECT (id, name)
FROM TableA
WHERE TableA.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns in table b

```
INSERT INTO TableB (id, name)
SELECT id, name
FROM TableA
WHERE id = 1
```